# Not getting the Join I want

Tags: mysql, sql, join

We are doing some pro bone work for a good cause and I'm having a hell of a time with a query. The coding has been done by many volunteers over the years which has an inevitable outcome.

I have two tables, A and B. What I need is a sum of of score_hours on a join between the two where the data is unique for each instance of only A.

Please keep in mind that both tables are quite big (10 to 50k+ each depending on time in the month).

Table A:

- id (pk, ai)
- uid (int)
- scores_date (timestamp (but for some reason only the actual date, not
  the time))
- score_hours (decimal 3,1)

Table B:

- id (pk, ai)
- uid (int)
- shift_date (timestamp)

There are many records in table B that have the uid we are looking for on several dates (the dates are not unique). Table A has multiple records for uid but on different days. So it could have 1 uid a day, but not 2 instances of 1 uid a day.

There are obviously more selectors for both tables, but they don't match in any way between the tables (although I do need to query them with simple "AND") so this is what I have to work with. I do need to join them because of the rest of the query, but so far I'm not getting the records I need within a decent time.

My attempts were:

This almost made it. But the execution time was disgusting and failed with some simple selectors.

```
SELECT SUM(score_hours)
FROM A
WHERE 
A.uid IN
(SELECT B.uid
FROM B
WHERE B.uid = "1")
```

This gives the right output but it joins one for every instance of a uid. Normally you can solve that by grouping, but the sum will still count all. So that is not an option:

```
SELECT SUM(score_hours)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.uid = B.uid
WHERE A.uid = "1"
```

*edit: Not only do I need to JOIN on uid, but there has to be something like this in it:

```
DISTINCT(date(m.shift_datum)) = DATE(d.dagscores_date)
```

It is actually a very basic query, except for the fact that a SUM is needed on a record which is not unique in regards to the Left join and that I need to JOIN on two tables at the same time.

If you need more data please tell me so. I can provide all.

Comment: Could you add some sample data and the expected output? Could help clarify what you're trying to acheive ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the duplicates from the table you're joining with, otherwise the cross-product creates multiple rows that get added into the sum.

```
SELECT SUM(score_hours)
FROM A
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT uid
      FROM B) AS B
ON A.uid = B.uid
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, this is not the first time you helped me here. I appreciate it very much! Your query is very(!) elegant, but it seems I forgot to mention something in the query. I will edit the question.

Comment: Hi Barmar, never mind. Based on your answer I have found the query i'm looking for. "SELECT SUM(score_hours) FROM A JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(shift_date) as datum, uid) as B on B.datum = A.scores_date WHERE A.uid = B.uid"

Comment: The general point is the same -- whatever you're joining on, make it `DISTINCT` in the subquery.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thank you for your answer. It was the select in the JOIN you provided that made it possible for me. I didn't even know that was even an option. You made my day (again)!